# JHipster "anonymoususer" login

Tags: jhipster, anonymous-users

I generated a monolithic application using JHipster and it has by default generated some users for me **(admin,system,user and anonymoususer)**  "anonymoususer". I tried to log in with **anonymoususer** but I can't because I don't have the password. Can anyone tell me the purpose of this user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> By default, JHipster comes with 4 different users:
>
> - “system”, who is mainly used by our audit logs, when something is done automatically
> - “anonymousUser”, who is given to anonymous users when they do an action
> - “user”, who is a normal user with “ROLE_USER” authorization. His default password is “user”
> - “admin”, who is an admin user with “ROLE_USER” and “ROLE_ADMIN” authorizations. His default password is “admin”
>
> https://www.jhipster.tech/security/